# How to NOT charge when USB debugging?

Tags: usb, charging, usb-debugging

I develop "on the road" using a laptop that's not connected to a power source, so when I debug on my android devices, they drain my laptop battery.  Unfortunately, the laptop is a MacBook Air so spare laptop batteries is not an option.  (I charge everything at home at night.)

Is there a setting to switch USB charging off, especially when debugging?

Comment: Depends on device in question, what is *your device*?

Comment: You could use a USB power bank with a Y-USB cable

Answer (score 0):

No there is not way to turn off charging.